# Set moment date after setting the utcOffset

Tags: momentjs

I'm looking to set a date on the `YYYYMMDD` that should be referencing to a date on a specific `utcOffset`. But I'm not sure what would be the best and elegant way to set this date after setting the `utcOffset`.

The close I can get is the following but its not the actual result I want. I need a way to first set the offset and then set the `YYYYMMDD` based on this offset.

```
moment.utc(ymdDate, 'YYYYMMDD').utcOffset(timeOffset)
```

**Example**:

In case I had a date like `20190420` that must be used on a moment object that should be referring to a different timezone and I do the following the date would result in April 19th.

```
moment.utc(20190420, 'YYYYMMDD').utcOffset(-300).format()
```

**Result**:
`2019-04-19T19:00:00-05:00`

**Expected Result**:
`2019-04-20T00:00:00-05:00`

Comment: I could not completely understand your question, what is your expected result? Maybe you can share a runnable snippet with sample values of `ymdDate` and `timeOffset`. I can't understand if you are looking for something like [`parseZone()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) / [`utcOffset(timeOffset, true)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) or if you simply have issue with displaying.

Comment: @VincenzoC Just added an exact test so you can check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`utcOffset`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) passing `true` as second parameter

> The `utcOffset` function has an optional second parameter which accepts a boolean value indicating whether to keep the existing time of day.
>
> - Passing `false` (the default) will keep the same instant in Universal Time, but the local time will change.
> - Passing `true` will keep the same local time, but at the expense of choosing a different point in Universal Time.

Here a live sample:

```js
console.log( moment.utc(20190420, 'YYYYMMDD').utcOffset(-300, true).format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```